# How is it possible to change Fragment to a variable Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist

Can you change a `Fragment` with a variable `Fragment` in `Java` like:

```
ArrayList<> fragmentToChange = new ArrayList(Fragment2);
```

That `Fragment` in `fragmentToChange` is variable, that means it could also be `Fragment3`, `Fragment4`, etc.

Then to change `Fragment`:

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, new fragmentToChange).commit();
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but how could it work? Is there any way to replace `fragmentToChange` to a variable that works?

Answer (score 1):

> `ArrayList<> fragmentToChange = new ArrayList(Fragment2)`

This is not a valid `ArrayList` as you can't pass in `Fragment2` to `ArrayList` constructor. Instead you need to create a list of fragments with the base `Fragment` class, and basically as any fragment extends from the base `Fragment` class, then you can put any type of fragment in the list.

```
ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentToChange = new ArrayList<>();
fragmentToChange.add(new Fragment1());
fragmentToChange.add(new Fragment2());
...
fragmentToChange.add(new Fragment4());
```

> `manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment1, new fragmentToChange).commit();`

This won't work as you are instantiating the `ArrayList` itself, which is not a valid fragment. But you need to pick a fragment from the list with `.get()` method, and no instantiation is needed as you have instantiated fragments before adding them in the `fragmentToChange` list.

```
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.place_holder, fragmentToChange.get(x)).commit(); // x is the index of the fragment in the list
```